# Why do my materials, assigned to different faces, only show in edit mode?

Tags: rendering, animation, materials

I downloaded an animated model.

I went into edit mode and assigned different textures, which look fine, but when I leave edit mode, it all turns to a single material. If I go back into edit I can see the colors again, but they show up wrong in the viewport/renders.

Edit mode:

[image]

Viewport , every frame, and renders:

[image]

Where are my materials going?

[image]

Showing that the render mode is selected:

[image]

**EDIT:** It appears the file I uploaded was broken, it does not animate. I think it is because I didn't pack the file, which seems to use data from the original abc file.

It seems to be using a modifier called "mesh sequence cache" to animate it.

[image]

I tried to pack the blend file for upload, but it said no files were added, so im not sure its possible to pack it.

Anyway i think the problem is that this cache is loading different verts for each frame, making it impossible to do what I'm trying to do? Unless someone knows a way. I tried applying the modifier, but it removed the animation.

Comment: I see colors in object mode in 2.93 and 3.0, probably a bug.

Comment: weird, i tried opening in both and it's still all yellow

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the 3d viewport top bar?

Comment: it works fine here, are you sure you've shared the latest version? what happens if you create a new object and give it another material? is it yellow as well?

Comment: @stackers if moonboots' idea about sharing the wrong file is wrong, it's quite likely you have hardware (or operating system) issues.